# Maven - how to work with multiple versions of dependencies?

Tags: java, rest, maven, jira, spring-boot

I have project which used JIRA REST Java Client. It worked fine until I tried to integrate it with Spring Boot. Since that I am not able to invoke `createWithBasicHttpAuthentication` from `AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory` without error. I get:

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.util.Args
```

So I added `HttpComponents Core blocking I/O(httpcore)` dependency to my `pom.xml`, but I after that I got

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.nio.NHttpMessageParserFactory
```

Which I resolved with adding `HttpComponents Core non-blocking I/O(httpcore-nio)` to `pom.xml`. Now I have

```
NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.nio.client.HttpAsyncClient.start()V
```

I've compared `dependency:tree` when project has spring boot parent and when it's commented out. It shown me that adding spring boot parent changes versions of my dependencies. You can check diff **[here](https://www.diffchecker.com/xtpt9pmq)**( on left without spring boot, on right with spring boot)

It seems that JIRA REST Java Client need older versions of some dependencies.
**How can I solve this problem?**

**pom.xml**

```
...

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

...

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore-nio</artifactId>
        <version>4.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

...
```

Comment: Well obviously as you are using quite old library version. Why not try upgrading the `com.atlassian` versions instead... However if adding the dependencies you added make it work, what is wrong with that?

Comment: There's no way to use the same dependency 2 times with different version (what version would java use if that was possible??) You have to find dependency versions that suit your case.

Comment: it seems you're a bit doomed. Maven resolves the dependencies by some sort of distance. So if you add the correct version in your pom the distance is 1, any transitive dependency (same groupId, artifactId) will have a greater distance. So adding dependencies with your version to your pom will always win. But if some other dependency requires a newer version there is no other way than to upgrade too. If in the end all is loaded with the same class loader you can't have two versions of the same class available.

Comment: If I were you I'd try asking Atlassian to update their library's dependencies. Not only are a number of its dependencies very old (they're using Spring 2.5.6, for example), judging by the version numbers some also seem to be Atlassian forks: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.1-atlassian-2 and org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.0-beta3-atlassian-1

Comment: This library is pretty odd. Quote from Atlassian marked saids :`This project is not actively supported by Atlassian, but feel free to contribute to it.`, but documentation is managed by Atlassian employees...

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix runtime in my Spring Boot application by overriding these properties in my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <httpasyncclient.version>4.0-beta3-atlassian-1</httpasyncclient.version>
    <httpclient.version>4.2.1-atlassian-2</httpclient.version>
</properties>
```

Note that there can be other problems if you decide to use http-client and/or httpassync client in your project (eg. using RestTemplate).

Atlassian should definitely upgrade the dependencies.